# Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, autofac

I am trying to connect [enFinder](http://elfinder.org/) file manager to my asp.net project with this [connector](http://elfinderaspnet.codeplex.com/documentation). I added Autofac Version 3. Afterwards I removed the reference and added a reference to Autofac 2.6. Now the following error occurs:

**Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If it needs 3 you have to use 3. Why did you go back to 2.6?

Comment: @levelnis because connector  it is for 2.6 version

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Delete all Autofac references in your project and add them again, using the correct Autofac DLL. The mismatch occurs when the reference you've added to your project via the *Add Reference* menu is not the same version as the actual file. This happens when you exchange the physical DLL file on your disk to which the reference in your project points.